# Unable to hardcode subtitles in FFmpeg on Mac to mov

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, mac, subtitles

I would like to hardcode subtitles using **FFmpeg**, I'm trying to do this using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i grdedFinal.mov -vf subtitles=portSbs.srt gradedFinalwithSubs.mov
```

which returns the following error:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.5 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libspeex --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-frei0r --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/1.5.2_1/include/openjpeg-1.5 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'grdedFinal.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2015-02-28 14:04:35
  Duration: 00:18:09.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11270 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-28 14:04:35
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1024x576, 9728 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 2500 tbn, 5k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-28 14:04:35
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fbeaa50bca0] Shaper: FriBidi 0.19.7 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 1.1.3 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fbeaa50bca0] Unable to open portSbs.srt
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fbeaa50ba80] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args 'portSbs.srt'
Error opening filters!
```

---

I followed [those instructions](http://www.renevolution.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-mac-os-x/) when installing **FFmpeg**:

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-frei0r --with-libass --with-libvo-aacenc --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opencore-amr --with-openjpeg --with-opus --with-rtmpdump --with-schroedinger --with-speex --with-theora --with-tools
```

---

## Feedback following comments

### 1st suggestion

Judging by the error message, it appears that something may be wrong with the **SRT** file, isn't it?

```
me-bash-3.2:/Volumes/Duracell$ ffmpeg -i gradedFinal.mov -i portSbs.srt -vf subtitles gradedFinalwithSubs.mov
ffmpeg version 2.8.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.5 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libspeex --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-frei0r --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/1.5.2_1/include/openjpeg-1.5 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'gradedFinal.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2015-02-28 14:04:35
  Duration: 00:18:09.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11267 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-28 14:04:35
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1024x576, 9728 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 2500 tbn, 5k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-02-28 14:04:35
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
portSbs.srt: Invalid data found when processing input
```

### Subtitle file

The subtitle file looks like that (extract):

```
1
00:02:25,000 —> 00:02:29,000
Falei com um homem que me disse que eu estava a usar
demasiada roupa


2
00:02:29,000 –> 00:02:31,000
Que com isso devo querer proteger-me de alguma coisa
```

#### File info

```
me-bash-3.2:/Volumes/Duracell$ file -I portSbs.srt
portSbs.srt: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

### 2nd, checking filter

```
me-bash-3.2:/Volumes/Duracell$ ffmpeg -help filter=subtitles
ffmpeg version 2.8.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.5 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libspeex --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-frei0r --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/1.5.2_1/include/openjpeg-1.5 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Filter subtitles
  Render text subtitles onto input video using the libass library.
    Inputs:
       #0: default (video)
    Outputs:
       #0: default (video)
subtitles AVOptions:
  filename          <string>     ..FV.... set the filename of file to read
  f                 <string>     ..FV.... set the filename of file to read
  original_size     <image_size> ..FV.... set the size of the original video (used to scale fonts)
  fontsdir          <string>     ..FV.... set the directory containing the fonts to read
  charenc           <string>     ..FV.... set input character encoding
  stream_index      <int>        ..FV.... set stream index (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
  si                <int>        ..FV.... set stream index (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
  force_style       <string>     ..FV.... force subtitle style
```

Comment: It says, "Unable to open portSbs.srt". Recheck the filename, and refer to it with the full path. If that doesn't work, try with another (known good) SRT.

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks very much for showing interest, I tried passing the full path `/Volumes/Duracell/portSbs.srt` but I arrived at the same error message. The file appears to be not damaged, I can open and edit it in a text editor.

Comment: Run `ffmpeg -i grdedFinal.mov -i portSbs.srt -vf subtitles gradedFinalwithSubs.mov` and paste the console output into your question.

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks very much for the helpful comments, I pasted additional output.

Comment: Let's confirm that subtitle filter is compiled in: `ffmpeg -help filter=subtitles` <-- does that say `unknown filter`?

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks for the continued interest in my problem, I just tested the command and it appears that the filter is compiled.

Comment: Can I suggest TextWrangler for editing these kinds of files on the Mac to avoid that kind of nastiness.

Comment: @stib The file was edited externally, I mostly use Atom or TW for text editing.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the subtitles file did not have **`-->`** but a **`–>`** with the **`–`** corresponding to the *[en dash](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/091502enem.htm)* that was placed in the file, which was edited by hand externally. It seems like the *en dash* sign was assigned to typing <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> in Mac TextEdit *(the functionality can be disabled in preferences)*.